# dbt Error retrieving modification time for file path/to/.#my_file.yml

Tags: gitignore, dbt

[dbt](https://docs.getdbt.com/) is giving me the error / warning

```
Error retrieving modification time for file /path/to/.#my_file.yml
```

which is an eyesore every time I run `dbt run` or similar.

My text editor creates the temporary file `.#my_file.yml` and I have no intention of changing my text editor.  I want to configure dbt so it knows to just ignore files like that entirely.  I found that dbt version 1.4.6 (which I am using) supports a `.dbtignore` file, as documented at https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbtignore

But nothing I try in the .dbtignore file seems to do the trick

```
.#*
"/path/to/.#my_file.yml"
.*my_file.yml
.*my_file
.*
\.*
```

I put my .dbtignore file at the root of my repo.  It is siblings with both `dbt_project.yml` and `.gitignore`.

Putting `*.yml` in my .dbtignore file causes dbt to create some weird error, which leads me to believe that dbt ignore is working.

My best conclusion right now is that the "modification time retrieval" part of dbt does not actually respect .dbtignore.

Does anybody know (1) why this behavior is happening and (2) a recommended way to suppress the error/warning message?